# Retrieve model from notification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

With Laravel, I can create database notifications.

Assuming, my notifications are about Resources (a model named `Resource`), I can give a resource instance to the notification constructor:

```
public function __construct(Resource $resource)
{
    $this->resource = $resource;
}

// ... 

public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'resource_id' => $this->resource->id
    ];
}
```

I would like to load notifications for a user and display some resources information. I can get all notifications and do something like this:

```
foreach ($user->notifications as $notification) {

    $resource_id = $notification->resource_id;
    $resource = Resource::find($resource_id);

    // Do something with resource information...
    echo $resource->name;

}
```

But it's slow (one query for each notification) and not à la Laravel. I would prefer something like:

```
foreach ($user->notifications as $notification) {

    // Do something with resource information...
    echo $notification->resource->name;

}
```

Ideally, it would like to have some kind of eager loading. Is there an elegant (or at least working) way to do this?

Comment: `Resource::whereIn('id', collect($user->notifications)->pluck('resource_id'))` might be a bit faster in that it only does 1 query. The same volume of data is still carried though. You could potentially serialise all that data in the notification but that's akin to caching them (which is also a solution).

Comment: Thanks! You can post this as an answer (and I will accept it!) About "but that's akin to caching them" -> I don't want to cache the result, because resource can change. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I believe laravel's find method and relationship access perform a "select *" by default. You might get a performance boost only selecting what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce your queries down to one by doing:

```
Resource::whereIn('id', collect($user->notifications)->pluck('resource_id'))
```

This will only perform a single SQL query.

Digging deeper into the Laravel database notifications. The Laravel boilerplate notification may be able to work with:

```
class User extends Model {
   // ...
   public function resourceNotifications() {
       $this->morphToMany(Resource::class, 'notifiable', 'notifications');
   }
}
```

Then retrieving all the corresponding notifications is as simple as:

```
$notifications = $user->resourceNotifications()->get();
```

Have not tested that part though.